# Getting error "No element type is defined for message NewOperationRequest"

Tags: eclipse, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java, axis2c

i'm reating WSDL file in eclipse from new -> other -> wsdl.
I want to use "type" instead of "elements". but when i creating stub of the wsdl getting below error:

```
2023-04-18 11:11:24,325 main DEBUG LoggerContext\[name=45ee12a7, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@76508ed1\] started OK.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenConfiguration.loadWsdl(CodeGenConfiguration.java:748)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.loadConfig(CodegenConfigLoader.java:328)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:53)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No element type is defined for message NewOperationRequest (see WS-I BP 1.0, R2204)
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:431)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:408)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:107)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenConfiguration.loadWsdl(CodeGenConfiguration.java:742)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder$WSDLProcessingException: 
           No element type is defined for message NewOperationRequest (see WS-I BP 1.0, R2204)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.addQNameReference(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1287)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.addQNameReference(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1215)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateBinding(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:729)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateEndpoint(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:547)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateEndpoints(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:499)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:370)
```

... 5 more

WSDL FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tns="urn:MRManagerService" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
name="MRManagerService" 
targetNamespace="urn:MRManagerService">
 <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:MRManagerService">
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    <xs:complexType name="NewOperation">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="param" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="NewOperationResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="out" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema> 
</wsdl:types>

 <wsdl:message name="NewOperationRequest">
   <wsdl:part type="xs:string" name="parameters"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="NewOperationResponse">
<wsdl:part element="xs:string" name="parameters"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:portType name="MRManagerService">
<wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:NewOperationRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:NewOperationResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:binding name="MRManagerServiceSOAP" type="tns:MRManagerService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:MRManagerService/NewOperation"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="MRManagerService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:MRManagerServiceSOAP" name="MRManagerServiceSOAP">
  <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

here i'm using below AXIS2 command to generate the stubs in terminal:

$AXIS2_HOME/bin/wsdl2java.sh -uri MRManagerService.wsdl -p org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide -d adb -s